# Encrypt a file using Botan library

Tags: c++, cryptography

I need to build something that is not very complicated, but efficient. I don't have much time to debug.

I don't know if this method is strong enough to encrypt a data to be displayed in a Qr code.

It will be compiled in Qt.

```
    #include <botan/botan.h>
    #include <botan/aes.h>
    #include <botan/kdf.h>
    #include <botan/pbkdf2.h>
    #include <botan/hmac.h>
    #include <botan/sha160.h>

    using namespace std;
    using namespace Botan;

    // .....

    bool BotanWrapper::EncryptFile(QString Source, QString Destination)
    {
    try
    {
    //Setup the key derive functions
    PKCS5_PBKDF2 pbkdf2(new HMAC(new SHA_160));
    const u32bit PBKDF2_ITERATIONS = 8192;

    //Create the KEY and IV
    KDF* kdf = get_kdf("KDF2(SHA-1)");

    //Create the master key
    SecureVector<byte> mMaster = pbkdf2.derive_key(48, mPassword.toStdString(), &mSalt[0], mSalt.size(),PBKDF2_ITERATIONS).bits_of();
    SymmetricKey mKey = kdf->derive_key(32, mMaster, "salt1");
    InitializationVector mIV = kdf->derive_key(16, mMaster, "salt2");

    string inFilename = Source.toStdString();
    string outFilename = Destination.toStdString();
    std::ifstream in(inFilename.c_str(),std::ios::binary);
    std::ofstream out(outFilename.c_str(),std::ios::binary);

    Pipe pipe(get_cipher("AES-256/CBC/PKCS7", mKey, mIV,ENCRYPTION),new DataSink_Stream(out));
    pipe.start_msg();
    in >> pipe;
    pipe.end_msg();

    out.flush();
    out.close();
    in.close();

    return true;
   }
   catch(...)
   {
    return false;
    }
   }
```

Comment: You should indent the code. It is easy to read then.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the Botan library, so I'll stick to some general recommendations.

---

Don't include whole namespaces at global scope, especially the `std` namespace.

---

The only use of Qt in this function is to accept `QString` arguments, with which we do nothing but convert to standard strings.  So why not remove the dependency, and allow the function to be used in non-Qt projects, by accepting the filenames as `const std::string&`?  We can keep the interface by providing a (header-only, trivially inlinable) wrapper separately as a convenience for use with Qt:

```
//encrypt.h
bool EncryptFile(const std::string& source, const std::string& destination);
```

```
//encrypt-qt.h
bool EncryptFile(QString source, QString destination)
{ return EncryptFile(source.toStdString(), destination.toStdString(); }
```

There's certainly no need to use `c_str()` when passing to the streams' constructors - a `std::string` is fine (and expected) there.

---

I'd probably go one further with the overloads, and provide a version that accepts a pair of streams, so that we could use this for network streaming or in-memory encryption:

```
//encrypt.h
bool EncryptFile(std::istream& source, std::ostream& destination);

bool EncryptFile(const std::string& source, const std::string& destination);
{
    try {
        std::ifstream in(source, std::ios::binary);
        std::ofstream out(destination, std::ios::binary);
        return EncryptFile(in, out);
    } catch (...) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

Why do we return true, even if writing the output failed?  For example, try passing `/dev/full` as the destination.  We could fix that:

```
return in && out;
```

Alternatively, we could arrange for the streams to throw exceptions:

```
    in.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::bad);
    out.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::bad);
```